# Why Clamtk is not scanning anything as well

Tags: clamtk

I have the same problem. Lenovo Thinkpad, Ubuntu 16.04 TSL loaded, clamTK loaded from software repository. I set clamTK to scan computer & 'zip' its done, files scanned show 0.
Could it be that as its the front end, could it be that its not conected to the back end?

Comment: Did you set ClamTK to `recursively scan directories`? What is "zip its done"?

Comment: Yes it is set to recursively scan directories & "zip its done" means the progress bar zips across in a flash & it says its done!

Comment: What directory are you scanning?

Answer (score 0):

The clamtk settings may not be selected correctly. By default, some settings may be disabled and you may have to activate them as below. Please check *Configuration -> Settings* menu for the items below and activate them by ticking/selecting;

- tick -> scan files larger than 20 MB
- tick -> scan directories recursively